# Anime about a boy who collects memory fragments so that princess will remember him

Tags: tsubasa-chronicle

It's about a boy who falls in love with a princess who makes a deal to save her life she must lose all memory of him. He has to go and collect memory fragments in the form of feathers and each one she remembers more.

Answer (score 16):

I think I might have found it:

[Tsubasa Chronicle](http://myanimelist.net/anime/177/Tsubasa_Chronicle)

[image: Tsubasa Chronicle]

> **Synopsis** *(taken from the site itself)*
>
> During an excavation at the mysterious ruins in Clow Country, Syaoran
>   discovers his childhood friend Princess Sakura appear on the site with
>   wings that disperse into many feathers. As the feather's disappear to
>   different dimensions, so does Sakura's memory. In attempts to save
>   Sakura's life and restore her memory, Syaoran travels through to
>   another world to find a solution. There's only one thing left he can
>   do. Travel through to different dimensions to collect Sakura's
>   feathers. Helping out with the quest is Kurogane, an exiled ninja from
>   Japan Country who wishes to return to his world, the runaway magician,
>   Fay, who desires to jump between each world never to return to his own
>   and the white meat-bun shaped creature, Mokona.

I think it fits the bill almost perfectly. As the synopsis points out, he **falls in love with Princess** Sakura, who loses her wings and are dispersed into many **feathers** which go to several worlds/dimensions, all of this **causing her to lose her memory**. It fails to mention anything about the deal, but as for everything else, I believe it's a dead giveaway.

Comment: It probably would be good to quote a summary of the series and how it matches by taking examples from the series you mention

Comment: It would be helpful to illustrate *why* you think this is the answer.

Comment: @Tyhja yes sir!

Comment: [This image](http://2.p.mpcdn.net/10509/160632/38.jpg) may confirm it. From chapter 2.

Comment: description fits. i think all that's lacking is for the OP to add "CLAMP all stars" to the question xD